# How to print select results from within a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I'm trying to debug (T-SQL).

It contains creates a temporary table, and has several update statements to update it with various data.

How can I insert statements to view the contents of this table at various points during the running of the stored procedure.

Ideally, I'll be running this directly from MS SQL Server Management Studio, and simple output to the Message frame will suffice.

Comment: Use `SELECT` statements against the temp table between the updates

Comment: If you are going to run this through SSMS, why not take the insides of the SP, and run this, with selects from the table in question at the points?

Comment: Silly me. I didn't read the Stored Procedure properly. All the existing selects were selecting into temporary tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be possible to SELECT what you need? Sorry if I misunderstood the question. Selected variables/tables will be returned as results